# Powershell - String Manipulation - getting dir from full file-path

Tags: string, powershell-3.0

Keep in mind I'm new to this and be gentle.

I have a full file path for a document **"C:\folder1\folder2\01.03.2017 - FileName.csv"** and I want to manipulate it to return the dir that the file is stored in (**C:\folder1\folder2**), minus the filename (**01.03.2017 - FileName.csv**).

I'm trying to make this modular so that it will work regardless of the amount of sub-folders a file sits in; we also won't know the FileName in advance, so again this needs to be modular and remove up to and including the last "**\**"

For background info on how this is currently built, I nicked a bit of code from a previous question I saw on StackOverflow:

```
Function Get-FileName($initialDirectory)
{   
 [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName(“System.windows.forms”) |
 Out-Null

 $OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
 $OpenFileDialog.initialDirectory = $initialDirectory
 $OpenFileDialog.filter = “All files (*.*)| *.*”
 $OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
 $OpenFileDialog.filename
} #end function Get-FileName

# *** Entry Point to Script ***

$originalData = Get-FileName -initialDirectory “c:\” | Out-String
Write-Host $originalData
$originalDir = $originalData.Split('\')
$originalDir
```

Running this currently prompts for an "open dialog box" you would see in Windows. You select a folder and the output is currently:

```
C:\folder1\folder2\01.03.2017 - FileName.csv

C:
folder1
folder2
01.03.2017 - FileName.csv
```

I've tried a few different `-join` attempts but none successful.

We will have an input of **C:\folder1\folder2\01.03.2017 - FileName.csv** as a variable **$originalData**.

We want the output to be **C:\folder1\folder2** as a variable **$originalDir**.

Comment: `(Get-Childitem itemname).DirectoryName`

Comment: How would this be used?
`(Get-ChildItem $originalData).DirectoryName` ?

Comment: this gives you file folder path, just try it

Comment: I'm probably being thick, but how would I point that to my data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Function Get-FileName($initialDirectory)
{   
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName(“System.windows.forms”) |
Out-Null

$OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
$OpenFileDialog.initialDirectory = $initialDirectory
$OpenFileDialog.filter = “All files (*.*)| *.*”
$OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
$OpenFileDialog.filename
} #end function Get-FileName

$originalData = Get-FileName -initialDirectory “c:\”
Write-Host $originalData
$originalDir = (Get-ChildItem $originalData).DirectoryName
```

you can use it like so, so take result or your function and use it with get-childitem.

edit: notice there's no `| Out-String` on the third to last line

Comment: Deleted my errors.
Corrected my script as per your edit; thanks for highlighting that you removed the `| Out-String` !
Many thanks for your quick reply / solution!